# performseguewithidentifier not working in IBAction method

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard

I have a storyboard with a segue connected between to views and the following code. For some reason the segue isn't being called and I am positive it is named correctly. I am wondering if it dosen't work because it is in an IBAction method or what. I am very confused so let me know if you have any ideas. thanks.

```
-(IBAction)didPressSubmit:(id)sender{

    NSString *idOfObject = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"idOfObject"];


    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"RequestsClass"];


    [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:idOfObject block:^(PFObject *myObj, NSError *error) {

        myObj[@"hasResponded"] = @"has";
        myObj[@"answer"] = textField.text;
        [myObj saveInBackground];



    }];

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"userDidRespond" sender:self];
}
```

Also there are no errors just nothing happens. I added an NSLog right above the line that calls it saying "about to perform segue" and it printed fine. So I'm not sure.

I am also getting this warning

```
Warning: A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnParseOperationOnMainThread() to debug
```

So i maybe i need to Deque main thread or something like that? Thanks

Comment: check that the segues name is userDidRespond.  Is this method being called? Set a breakpoint to check.

Comment: can you post your prepareForSegue method please? Seems the problem is there.

Comment: How is your segue connected in the storyboard?

Comment: Try to add an `NSLog(@"Segue: %@", segue.identifier);` in `prepareForSegue`. You can at least see if _any_ segue is getting called.

Comment: Have you push to another ViewController?

Comment: @bauerMusic I had the same problem as OP and just adding the `prepareForSegue` method fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Move this line :

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"userDidRespond" sender:self];
```

inside the block.

Like this :

```
-(IBAction)didPressSubmit:(id)sender{

NSString *idOfObject = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"idOfObject"];


PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"RequestsClass"];


[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:idOfObject block:^(PFObject *myObj, NSError *error) {

    myObj[@"hasResponded"] = @"has";
    myObj[@"answer"] = textField.text;
    [myObj saveInBackground];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"userDidRespond" sender:self];

}];

}
```

I hope this will do the trick.

Comment: I tried that and it still did not work. No errors or anything. Just didn't perform the segue. I have updated my answer with one of the warnings which may be useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can also navigate from one view controller to another by following code without using `performSegueWithIdentifier` method.

```
 UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
 viewController *viewObj = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController"];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewObj animated:YES];
```

For this you have to give storyboardID to viewcontroller as "viewController" in your storyboard. And by this method you can also set objects for next view.

Comment: This makes sense but when I used it it did not do anything. I have updated my answer though to include one of the warnings I'm gettings which might be useful. Thanks!

Comment: yes, in your code one block is running. so it is running in thread. so make one method and put this code of push view controller in that method. then call that after your ibaction. or call after some time interval.

Answer (score 0):

The Parse warning you are getting is unrelated and should go in a different question. It is telling you that you are trying to connect to Parse (maybe a login in?) on the main thread. You want to do this asynchronously on a different thread with a completion block.

Something like this: (in SWIFT)

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(userName.text, password: passwordField.text, block: {
        (user,error) in
        completion(error == nil)
    })
```

Parse has many examples in Objective-C as well.